# calculate the optimal order of a series of transformations

Tags: algorithm

Not sure if I should ask here or a different stack exchange but.

Basically I'm wondering if there is a known way to find the shortest path between two values given a number of potential transformations?

Brute force solution/example in python

```py
from itertools import permutations, groupby

start = ["A", "B", "C", "D"]
goal = ["A", "X", "C", "Y"]

Transforms = [
    (None,None,"B","D"),
    ("F",None,None,"Y"),
    (None,"X","C",None),
    (None,None,"G","Y"),
    ("D","X",None,None),
    (None,"X",None,None)
]

def apply_transform(value, transform):
    for x in range(4):
        if transform[x] is None: continue
        value[x] = transform[x]

perms = permutations(range(len(Transforms)))
results = []

for order in perms:
    value = start.copy()
    moves = 0
    for o in order:
        moves += 1
        apply_transform(value, Transforms[o])
        if value == goal:
            results.append([moves, order[0:moves]])
            break

# just printing sorted unique in a formated way...I'd be just picking the first one not listing all potential ones
results.sort( key=lambda x: x[0])
results = list(k for k,_ in groupby(results))
print("\n".join(f"moves {m} | {' -> '.join(str(s) for s in ms)}" for m,ms in results))
```

results that correctly move the start to the goal.

```
moves 2 | 3 -> 2
moves 3 | 0 -> 3 -> 2
moves 3 | 3 -> 5 -> 2
moves 3 | 5 -> 3 -> 2
moves 4 | 0 -> 3 -> 5 -> 2
moves 4 | 0 -> 5 -> 3 -> 2
moves 4 | 5 -> 0 -> 3 -> 2
```

so picking the first item in the sorted list as the lowest number of transformations. (applying transformation "3" and then transformation "2").

Obviously, this exact brute force "algorithm" can be improved by breaking out of a permutation if its already started getting longer than the lowest number of jumps... but is there a better solution to this problem I'm not seeing? Some sort of graph? Permutations aren't the best for speed but it might be the only option. Are there other small optimizations that can be done with this?

Comment: Is it allowed by the problem description to use a transformation more than once? BTW one possible optimization would be to find transformations that can't possibly be part of the solution.

Comment: There isn't really a problem description. I'm trying to come up with a natural way to switch between states that have several sub parameters with "Events" that happen in combinations to make the switch. I'm making the question more generic in the hopes its more useful. ie a formen of {enviroment, housing, political, etc} where a event that changes the environment like a disaster, also changes the political structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible optimization would be to find transformations that have to be last ones, and work your way backwards.

So, here only transformations 2 and 5 can be the last ones, and 5 is the subgroup of 2 so it can be ignored (one more optimization: ignore transformations that are parts of other transformations), and the only that remains is 2.

Now you are looking how to reach state (A, *, *, Y) using remaining transformations. Transformations 1 and 3 are the only candidates, and 3 -> 2 makes the solution.

This algorithm is a bit complicated, because it requires recursion and backtracking (if you do it the easy way, depth-first), or some queue processing (if you do it the better way, breadth-first), but it will be faster than trying all possible permutations.

Comment: Honestly faster than all possible permutations is "good enough" especially when the transformations are simple but there are a lot of them. I'll mark this as the answer if no better solution is given.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as a graph.  Each value is a node, and the transformations are edges.  There are known algorithms for the shortest path in a graph, e. g. Dijkstra or A*.